# Как вывести изображение с известным началом имени?

Tags: php

Юзер загружает лого, файлу присваивается имя: `userID<имя файла>.<расширение>`
Как потом вывести лого на страницу?

```
<img src="/images/<?php echo $userID;?>???.???">
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользоваться функцией [glob](http://www.php.su/functions/?glob) - она умеет по маске возвращать список файлов. Нужно только корректно обработать ситуацию, если найдется несколько файлов или не найдется ничего. Где-то так (давно на php не писал):

```
$f = glob("images/$userID*");
if (count($f) == 0) {
    echo "<img src=\"/images/none.png\">";
} else {
    echo "<img src=\"/images/".$f[0].".png\">";
}
```

Comment: Семушин Сергей, в этом случае лучше написать комментарий автору, чем сразу менять чужой текст. Ваши правки могут быть расценены как значительно меняющие авторский смысл.

Comment: Хорошо, так и сделаем :)

1) судя по вопросу, после $userId и перед расширением должна быть точка  

2) glob возвращает путь к файлу, а не только его название  

3) в данном случае логичнее использовать одинарные кавычки, дабы не экранировать двойные внутри строки

Comment: @СемушинСергей Спасибо.